# Selecting one row from duplicate rows mysql/sqlite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, unique

My table (Data_A) consists of columns:

```
_id | mac_address | bit
```

There are multiple rows with same `mac_address` and bit may be 0/1.
I want to construct a sqlite query where I want to select _id of all the rows such that each row has its unique `mac_address` and PREFERENCE should be given to selecting a row which has `bit = 1`.

Answer (score 3):

I think the following works in SQLite:

```
select a.*
from data_a a
where a._id = (select aa._id
               from data_a aa
               where aa.mac_address = a.mac_address
               order by aa.bit desc
               limit 1
              );
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, you can simply select entire rows from groups with min()/max():

```
SELECT _id, mac_address, max(bit)
FROM Data_A
GROUP BY mac_address
```